# Iterate through nested loops and remove specific index that matches the condition

Tags: javascript

I have a temp array which originally looks something like this :

```
[{emp_id:1, acitivty:'run'}, {emp_id: 2, activity:'climb'}, {emp_id:1,activity:'swim'} .....]
```

Now, what I want is to merge the objects with the same `emp_id`. It should look like this:

```
[{emp_id:1, activity:'run', activity2:'swim'}, {emp_id:'2',activity:'climb'} .....]
```

Instead, I only got this, not showing the rest of the objects in the array:

```
[{emp_id:'1', activity:'run', activity2:'swim'}]
```

In my code, when the condition is met and the merging and splicing is done, I decrement the `z` because I think after splicing, the array will be reindexed and I think the array length will still be as is.
What seems to be the problem?

```
for(var z = 0; z < temp.length; z++) {
   for(var x = 1; x < temp.length; x++) {
      if(temp[z].emp_id == temp[x].emp_id) {
         var ot_key = 'ot_time'+x+1;
         var status_key = 'status'+x+1;
         var dtr_key = 'dtr_out'+x+1;
         Object.assign(temp[z], {
            [ot_key] : temp[x].ot_time,
            [status_key] : temp[x].status,
            [dtr_key] : temp[x].dtr_out
         })
         temp.splice(x, 1);
         z--;
      } 
   }
}
```

Comment: btw, do you really want to add a counter to a property? how do you read it later? why not take an array?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, i will be having a dynamic header in a table

Comment: How is C# relevant here? Or JSON?

Comment: is your spelling right? `activity`?

Comment: You should use array like [{emp_id:1, acitivty: ['run', 'swim']}, {emp_id: 2, activity:'climb'},  .....]
this is better approach

Comment: @SuhagLapani88 Oh, i'll try. thanks

Comment: @NinaScholz yes, and i dont think it matters since it is dynamic anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the spelling, you could take an object and store the wanted postfix in the objects. later take the payload.

For example have a look to the final object before getting the values and mapping only the `payload` property:

```
{
    1: {
        index: 3,
        payload: { emp_id: 1, activity: "run", activity2: "swim" }
    },
    2: {
        index: 2,
        payload: { emp_id: 2, activity: "climb" }
    }
}
```

Here `emp_id` is taken as key for grouping and because of the wanted structure an `index` is grouped as well for having a value for futher activities.

```js
var data = [{ emp_id: 1, activity: 'run' }, { emp_id: 2, activity: 'climb' }, { emp_id: 1, activity: 'swim' }],
    result = Object
        .values(data.reduce((r, { emp_id, activity }) => {
            if (r[emp_id]) r[emp_id].payload['activity' + r[emp_id].index++] = activity;
            else r[emp_id] = { index: 2, payload: { emp_id, activity } };
            return r;
        }, {}))
        .map(({ payload }) => payload);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A better approach is to use an array for the activities.

```js
var data = [{ emp_id: 1, activity: 'run' }, { emp_id: 2, activity: 'climb' }, { emp_id: 1, activity: 'swim' }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { emp_id, activity }) => {
        if (r[emp_id]) r[emp_id].activity.push(activity);
        else r[emp_id] = { emp_id, activity: [activity] };
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! can you explain further tho? :) I'm new to this -.-

Comment: why not to use `object.keys.length` to get next index postfix

Comment: i did the same, however i though it would be good to remove, else i need this extra `map` thing. Extra loop

Comment: @xdeepakv, you could but it goes messy if you have some more wanted properties in the objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use array [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to get an array of activities grouped by `emp_id` which I think much cleaner.

```js
const temp = [{emp_id:1,activity:"run"},{emp_id:2,activity:"climb"},{emp_id:1,activity:"swim"}];
const res = Object.values(temp.reduce((ac, { emp_id, activity }) => {
  ac[emp_id] = ac[emp_id] || {emp_id, activity: []}
  ac[emp_id].activity.push(activity)
  return ac;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: u need another `reduce or map` to property in given output format.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you can do in `2 loop`, one for `reduce` another to collect output `array.values`.
Fast and better.

**Note :** If you dont want to use Object.keys, use 2nd solution

```js
const data = [
  { emp_id: 1, activity: "run" },
  { emp_id: 2, activity: "climb" },
  { emp_id: 1, activity: "swim" }
];
const result = data.reduce((obj, { emp_id, activity }) => {
  if (!obj[emp_id]) obj[emp_id] = { emp_id };
  const count = Object.keys(obj[emp_id]).length;
  obj[emp_id] = {
    ...obj[emp_id],
    [`activity_${count}`]: activity
  };
  return obj;
}, {});
let finalResult = Object.values(result)
console.log(finalResult);

// If you dont want to use Object.keys


const result2 = data.reduce((obj, { emp_id, activity }) => {
  if (!obj[emp_id]) obj[emp_id] = { count: 0, data: {} };
  const count = obj[emp_id].count + 1;
  obj[emp_id] = {
    data: {
      ...obj[emp_id].data,
      [`activity_${count}`]: activity
    },
    count: count
  };
  return obj;
}, {});
let finalResult2 = [];
for (let key in result2) {
  const { data } = result2[key];
  finalResult2.push(data);
}
console.log(finalResult2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; color: blue!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this

```
var data = [{
  emp_id: 1, activity: 'run'
}, {
  emp_id: 2, activity: 'climb'
}, {
  emp_id: 1, activity: 'swim'
}];

var lookup = {};
var counter = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  if (lookup[item.emp_id]) {
    var found = lookup[item.emp_id];
    lookup[item.emp_id]['activity' + counter[item.emp_id]] = item.activity;
    counter[item.emp_id]++;
    data.splice(i, 1);
    i--;
  } else {
    lookup[item.emp_id] = item;
    counter[item.emp_id] = 2;
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `array.reduce()` like this:

**Be careful, your initial array has a spelling mistake in `activity` property.**

```js
let x =[
         {emp_id:1, activity:'run'},
         {emp_id: 2, activity:'climb'},
         {emp_id:1,activity:'swim'}
       ];

let finalResult =
     x.reduce((result, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) =>
       {
         return [...result, 
            arr.filter(f => f.emp_id === currentValue.emp_id &&
                            !result.find(r=>r.emp_id === f.emp_id)
                      )
               .reduce((subResult, currentItem, index) => 
                { 
                  return {emp_id:currentItem.emp_id, ...subResult, ...{[`activity${index ==0 ? '' : '_' + (index+1)}`]:currentItem.activity}}; 
                }, undefined)
              ];
       }, [])
      .filter(item=> !!item);

console.log(finalResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

> this solution will also take care if you have more then two
>   activity have same id

```js
var x=[{emp_id:1, acitivty:'run'}, {emp_id: 2, activity:'climb'}, {emp_id:1,activity:'swim'},{emp_id:1,activity:'swim3'} ]

let myMap = new Map()

x.forEach(element =>{
let alreadyExist=myMap.has(element.emp_id)  
if(alreadyExist){
let tempelement=myMap.get(element.emp_id)
tempelement.count=tempelement.count?++tempelement.count:2;
tempelement['acitivty'+tempelement.count]=element.activity
myMap.set(element.emp_id, tempelement)
}else{
myMap.set(element.emp_id, element)
}
});

//convert map to Array
let newArray=Array.from(myMap.values())

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArray))

//[{"emp_id":1,"acitivty":"run","count":3,"acitivty2":"swim","acitivty3":"swim3"},{"emp_id":2,"activity":"climb"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would heed @NinaScholz's advice to use an array for `activity` values which will be  much easier to handle afterwards when compared to testing for different related properties (and to fix the spelling of `acitivty`), but take a naive approach in creating a result array by using `forEach()`, which I find more readable. For example:

```js
const source = [{emp_id: 1, activity: 'run'}, {emp_id: 2, activity: 'climb'}, {emp_id: 1, activity: 'swim'}];
let results = [];

// For each source item, check whether a result object with the current emp_id exists.
source.forEach(o => results.filter(r => r.emp_id === o.emp_id).length == 1
    // Add activity to existing result object.
    ? results[o.emp_id].activity.push(o.activity) 
    // Create a new result object
    : results.push({ emp_id: o.emp_id, activity: [o.activity] })
    );

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```